# Zend DB Left Join

Tags: php, sql, database, zend-framework

I realize that Zend DB, Left Join SQL query return NULL for the join column. Is this true?

For example:

```
$selectmatchedtime = $this->dbo->select()
            ->from(array('v'=>'table1'))
            ->joinLeft(array('vc'=>'table2'),'vc.vid = v.vid');
```

Return **null** for all vid...

Comment: just under this statement use die($selectmatchedtime); to dump the sql query and run it in database and see what result you get.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `vid` column in your query belongs to two tables, but obviously can store only a single value in the result set. To resolve the problem, make an alias for it, stating explicitly which table should be used:

```
$selectmatchedtime = $this->dbo->select()
            ->from(array('v'=>'table1'))
            ->joinLeft(array('vc'=>'table2'),'vc.vid = v.vid')
            ->columns(array('vid'=>'v.vid'));
```

Comment: if 'vc.vid = v.vid' then does it matter which vid is fetched?

Comment: It's LEFT JOIN, remember. For the rows that won't find its match on the right side, `vc.vid` (as all the other values of `vc.*`) will be NULL.

Comment: is it possible to include `and` with `joinLeft`?